# VPS services down due: No space left on device? Really?

Tags: vps, httpd, failed

I have a VPS running for a long time. It's for some small websites and for private mail for myself and family. According to directadmin I was only using 10 gigabyte of space and the VPS should have 50 gigabyte.

Last week I was testing SQL queries. Yesterday I got the first error when phpmyadmin could not perform one SQL due to: no space left. Small queries did work. I updated my VPS plan from 50gb to 150gb and did an update:

```
yum check-update
yum update -y
/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/build update
/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/build update_versions
reboot
```

After the reboot Apache, Exim, MariaDB and Named stopped. Directadmin is running so I can access  it but all my websites and my email are now unreachable.

When I performed:

```
[root@server domains]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: resources)

Jun 20 21:53:32 server.intermagic.nl systemd[1]: httpd.service failed to run 'start' task: No space left on device
Jun 20 21:53:32 server.***.nl systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 20 21:53:32 server.***.nl systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 20 21:53:32 server.***.nl systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jun 20 21:57:43 server.***.nl systemd[1]: httpd.service failed to run 'start' task: No space left on device
Jun 20 21:57:43 server.***.nl systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 20 21:57:43 server.***.nl systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

After a lot of reboots I now get:

```
[admin@server tmp]$ systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources)
```

What could be the cause of it? Really too much of bad SQL queries?
And what can I do about it? I can re-install everything, but...

**Edit 1:**

```
Filesystem                          Size    Used    Avail  Use%   Mounted on 
devtmpfs                            1.9G    0       1.9G   0%     /dev
tmpfs                               1.9G    0       1.9G   0%     /dev/shm
tmpfs                               1.9G    89M     1.8G   5%     /run
tmpfs                               1.9G    0       1.9G   0%     /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_root  48G     20G     28G    42%    /
/dev/vda1                           497M    262M    236M   53%    /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp   1014M   1014M   0      100%   /tmp
```

Comment: What does `df -h` say?

Comment: Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

devtmpfs                            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev

tmpfs                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               1.9G   89M  1.8G   5% /run

tmpfs                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_root   48G   20G   28G  42% /

/dev/vda1                           497M  262M  236M  53% /boot

/dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp  1014M 1014M     0 100% /tmp
Is it the /dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_root ??

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of  `pvs` and `lsblk` ?

Answer (score 2):

From the `df -h` output it should be pretty easy to spot the *Use* `100%` with *Avail* `0`.

Your `/tmp` is full. Adding capacity to the `/` doesn't solve this.

The question on [how to increase directadmin tmp](https://forum.directadmin.com/threads/how-to-increase-directadmin-tmp.53025/) is discussed on DirectAdmin forums.

Comment: After root> rm -rf /tmp/* my server was running again. thanks

Comment: Well that was a bold choice, to "*read mail really fast*" it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the system has enough free extents (`PFree` column) with:

```
sudo pvs
```

If you have enough free LVM extents you can expand the `/tmp` volume with `300MB` by running:

```
sudo lvextend -L +300m --resizefs /dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp
```

If you don't have enough free extents:

- You need to see on which /dev/vd[ab][0-9] block device you have /tmp. `lsblk` will help you identify this.
- Expand the disk of the VM that is storing the /dev/vd[ab][0-9] block device. This can be done online in modern clouds and virtualization platforms.
- Ask the VM to rescan the block device for size changes. Run as `root` user the following command, make sure you use the right `vd...` device: `echo 1 > /sys/block/vd..../device/rescan`
- Expand the LVM physical disk: `pvresize /dev/vd....`
- Expand the LV and the filesystem: `lvextend -L +300m --resizefs /dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp`
- no reboot should be needed

You can also use [this script](https://github.com/mircea-vutcovici/scripts/blob/master/vol_resize.sh) as `root` and it will generate the command to expand the `/tmp` volume: `sudo bash vol_resize.sh --block-device /dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp`

Comment: I got my server running after Esa his reply. I will look into your answer because I suspect the problem will re-occur. When I now check the sudo pvs command (after removing tmp and a reboot) I have pfree=0 and Psize <49.51g